# Number Theory - Order of $p^2$

Tags: number-theory

How can you show that if $p$ is prime then the numbers with maximum possible order modulo $p^2$ is $\phi(\phi(p^2))$.

I tried finding order(a) modulo 9, and obtained the following: $1$ is $1$, $2$ is $6$,$3$ doesn't exist, $4$ is $3$, $5$ is $6$, $6$ doesn't exist, $7$ is $3$, and $8$ is $2$.

So maximum possible order is 6, and 2 and 5 have maximum possible order. Also $$\phi(\phi(3^2)) = \phi(6) = \phi(2)\phi(3) = 2$$ and so I verified that this is true. Now how do I go about proving the statement? Where do I even start?

Comment: I don't understand the statement. Especially "the numbers .... is ...."

Comment: @mercio It indeed is a little confusing, but I think it means: the number of elements in $\;\Bbb Z_{p^2}=\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z\;$ which are generators of the group of units $\;\Bbb Z^*_{p^2}\;$ is $\;\varphi(\varphi(p^2))\;$ .

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm an engineering student taking a math course on number theory and we don't talk about generators and groups and all that since that is deemed to be too complex for the course, so I have a hard time understanding the surface level of number theory without the group theory aspect of it.

Answer (score 1):

(1) The group of units $\;\Bbb Z_{p^2}\;$ is cyclic and it has order $\;\varphi(p^2)=p(p-1)\;$

(2) A cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ has exactly $\;\varphi(n)\;$ generators .

Now put together (1)+(2) and deduce what you want.